# What's the correct word for Japanese animations in Portuguese (anime or animê)?

Tags: ortografia, pronúncia, estrangeirismos

What's the correct word in Portuguese to talk about Japanese animations (anime). I was googling for it and found some mismatched answers.

I'm asking about writing, but also about the pronunciation of the word.

Comment: Apparently it's [animé](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/anime) in European Portuguese. this is news to me.

Comment: @GitGud Não me interesso muito pelo assunto, mas tenho colegas que gostam e sempre ouço eles falarem (em pt_br) _anime_, com tônica na sílaba _ni_

Comment: Animé is new to me. I'm used to see anime, but it seems to be something hard to define.

Comment: @gmauch Eu ouço o mesmo em Portugal

Comment: @gmauch lá por toda a gente dizer *anime* não quer dizer nada, o Git tem razão é animé em Português de Portugal.

Comment: Animé? Será que o pessoal pensa que eles vêm da França em vez do Japão? Quanto à pronúncia, me parece que o japonês não marca tanto as sílabas tônicas quanto as línguas ocidentais. Daí por exemplo *caqui* (a fruta) ser pronunciada como paroxítona no Rio Grando do Sul e como oxítona no resto do país. Talvez o mesmo valha para anime/animê.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### [English] <sub>(português mais abaixo)</sub>

This answer regards **Brazilian Portuguese** only.

Between "anime" and "animê" in the context of Portuguese, the closest writing to the original *transliteration* is "anime", but the closest writing to the original *pronunciation* is "animê".

### Pronunciation

The word "anime" is the abbreviation of "**アニメー**ション" (**Animē**shon (click [here](https://translate.google.com/#auto/ja/animation) to hear), from English "animation"). This "メー" (mē) is a long "メ" (IPA /me/), i.e. in Japanese the pronunciation of　"メー" is something like "/meee/" (animeeeshon), stressing the `e`.

Therefore, based on that, the correct pronunciation would be "animê" ¹.

Despite this, many people don't care about it and say "an**í**me" (including me, lol), treating "anime" as if it is a whole word, turning it paroxytone (the penultimate syllable stressed, in case, `ni`), but as said, this isn't correct, if taking in consideration the original pronunciation.

### Writing

The writing is a bit more complicated to say. Both writings are used, though "anime" is much more common and globally used.

In modified [Hepburn transliteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization), the macron ( ¯ ) is used as a diacritic on long vowels, in case on `e` in "animēshon".
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization#Long_vowels),

> Since this diacritical sign [the macron] is usually missing on typewriter and computer keyboards, the circumflex ( ˆ ) is often used in its place

Though, at least **I**, very rarely see this substitution. But anyway, the abbreviation in Japanese is "アニメ" (a-ni-me), and not "アニメー" (a-ni-mē), so it's noticeable that the circumflex wouldn't have anything to do with Hepburn romanization.

Now this leads us to Portuguese.

The [Brazilian Academy of Letters](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario) (I don't know in case of Portugal's academy) doesn't recognizes "animê", but only "anime", but referring to the word in Portuguese, that means [a type of resin](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/anime%20_903359.html) ². From the dictionaries I verified, the only that recognizes anime as the Japanese animations are the [Priberam Dictionary](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/anime) and the [Aulete Dictionary](http://www.aulete.com.br/anim%C3%AA), in which both are accented, and on Priberam, "anime" points to "animê".

Another word that comes from the Japanese pop culture is "mangá" ¹, that also isn't officially recognized, but only, again, [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/mang%C3%A1) and [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/mang%C3%A1) have it. Even tough, in Brazil, "mangá" is accepted as an accented oxytone by practically every Portuguese speaker and no one have any doubt about it.
As it was concluded above, the correct pronunciation is "animê", oxytone. Therefore, if "mangá" which is equally foreign and oxytone, is accented, then also "animê".
Furthermore, oxytones ending with `a(s)`, **e(s)**, `o(s)`, and `em/ens` [are accented](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/fono/fono9.php).

However, it's not incorrect to write "anime", because it's nothing but the romanization ([rōmaji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C5%8Dmaji)) from the original Japanese, instead of the Portuguese adaptation (accented). But according to Portuguese norms, the correct writing is accented. So in formal documents it should be written accented. But although it can also be written as "anime", the *pronounce* still is "animê".

**Notes:**
1. In **Portugal**, animê is accented with an acute (animé), and mangá does not have accent.
2. The word "anime" in Portuguese (the resin) is very very rare (I didn't even knew that there's a resin with this name).

---

### [Português]

Esta resposta refere-se apenas ao **português brasileiro**.

Entre "anime" e "animê", a forma mais próxima da *transliteração* é "anime", mas a mais próxima da *pronúncia* original é "animê".

### Pronúncia

A palavra "anime" é a forma abreviada de "**アニメ**ーション" (**animē**shon, que vem do inglês "**anima**tion"). Esse "メー" (mē) é a forma alongada de "メ" (me, pronunciado mê), ou seja, em japonês a pronúncia de "メー" seria "mêêê" (animêêêshon), dando ênfase no `e`.

Portanto, baseando-se nisso, a pronúncia correta seria "animê" ¹.

Mas apesar disso, muita gente não se importa com isso e fala "an**í**me" mesmo (inclusive eu, rsrs), tratando "anime" como se fosse uma palavra inteira, tornando-a paroxítona (a penúltima sílaba como tônica, no caso `ni`), mas como disse, não é o correto, se levando em consideração a pronúncia original.

### Grafia

Já a grafia, é um tanto mais complicado dizer. As duas formas são utilizadas, apesar de "anime" ser muito mais comum e utilizado globalmente.

Na [transliteração Hepburn](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_Hepburn) modificada, o mácron ( ¯ ) é utilizado como diacrítico em vogais alongadas, no caso o `e` em "animēshon".
Segundo a [Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization#Long_vowels),

> Uma vez que esse sinal diacrítico [o mácron] geralmente está ausente em máquinas de escrever e teclados de computador, o circunflexo (^) é comumente utilizado no lugar.

Apesar de que **eu** muito raramente vejo essa substituição. Mas de qualquer forma, a abreviação em japonês é "アニメ" (a-ni-me), e não "アニメー" (a-ni-mē), então percebe-se que o circunflexo não teria relação com romanização Hepburn.

Agora isso nos leva ao português.

A [Academia Brasileira de Letras](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario) (não sei no caso da de Portugal) não reconhece "animê", apenas "anime", mas se referindo à palavra do português, que significa [um tipo de resina](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/anime%20_903359.html) ². Dos dicionários que verifiquei, os únicos dicionários que reconhecem anime se referindo às animações japonesas é o [Dicionário Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/anime) e o [Dicionário Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/anim%C3%AA), em que em ambos está acentuado, e no Priberam "anime" aponta para "animê".

Uma outra palavra vinda da cultura pop japonesa é "mangá" ¹, que também não é reconhecida oficialmente, mas apenas pelo [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/mang%C3%A1) e [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/mang%C3%A1). Apesar disso, no Brasil, esta é aceita como oxítona acentuada por praticamente ou até mesmo todo falante do português e ninguém tem dúvida quanto a isso.
Como foi concluído acima, a pronúncia correta é "animê", oxítona. Portanto, se "mangá" que é igualmente estrangeira e oxítona, recebe acento, logo "animê" também.
Além disso, oxítonas terminadas em `a(s)`, **e(s)**, `o(s)` e `em/ens` [são acentuadas](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/fono/fono9.php).

Porém, não é incorreto escrever "anime", pois é nada mais do que a romanização ([rōmaji](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C5%8Dmaji)) do original japonês, ao invés da adaptação para o português (acentuado). Mas pelas normas do português, o correto é com acento, inclusive em documentos formais deve-se escrever a forma acentuada. Mas apesar de também poder ser escrito como "anime", a *pronúncia* continua sendo "animê".

**Notas:**
1. Em **Portugal**, animê é com acento agudo (animé), e mangá não tem acento.
2. A palavra anime (quando se referindo à resina) é muito muito rara (eu na verdade nem sabia que existe uma resina com esse nome).

Comment: Grande resposta, parabéns!

Comment: Quando falta o macron, pode-se simplesmente usar a outra notação e prolongar a vogal com outra vogal: `animeeshon`, `ooki`, `toukyou`, etc. Como no alemão, em que quando falta a trema pode-se simplesmente acrescentar um e (que é o que significa a trema). É escusado inventar (usando acentos circunflexos)...

Comment: Eu poria no **topo** da resposta a nota acerca da resposta ser para pt-BR.

Comment: Considering that the original Japanese pronunciation is [aꜜnime], with a drop in pitch after "a", I think the best approximation would be _ánime_, actually...

Comment: `Os únicos dicionários que reconhecem anime se referindo às animações japonesas é o Dicionário Priberam e o Dicionário Aulete` O Aurélio tambem tem [anime](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/865/64).

Comment: @Earthliŋ Dos que verifiquei, "Os únicos dicionários ...."   Não tenho um Aurélio para que eu pudesse verificar. Eu até pensei na possibilidade de ter no Aurélio, mas como não tenho, e nem é online...

Comment: in Japanese the pronunciation of　"メー" is something like "/meee/" (animeeeshon), stressing the e. - This is not correct. Japanese does not in fact have stressed syllables. It has long vowels, but this is not the same. It also has pitch accent (as in Earthling's comment), which is the closest thing it has to something like the concept of stressed syllables in other languages, but this is even more different. Japanese does often convert the vowel in the stressed syllable of a loanword from English into a long vowel, but there is not a 1:1 correspondence between the two.

Comment: @hippietrail By "stressing" I meant that the "e" has emphasis. And when I said "the closest" this should be understood as "between the anime and animê pronounce, the animê is the closest". I'm not saying that the pronounce in Japanese is exactly this, but in the context of Portuguese, it is pronounced that way.

Comment: Everything else you said looked correct to me. I just wanted to try to clear up any misunderstanding. The "e" in "anime" in Japanese has no emphasis whatsoever. When Japanese words are borrowed into other languages such as English and Portuguese as you have noted a final "e" like this does seem to acquire some kind of emphasis to maintain a pronunciation more like the Japanese original that would otherwise be lost. The accent in English "saké" from Japanese being a well-known example to stop people pronouncing it the same as "sake".

Answer (score 6):

My Brazilian Portuguese dictionary (Aurélio, 5ª edição) does have an entry for anime

> **anime**
> [Japonês]
> *Substantivo masculino.*
>
> 1. Animação (6) japonesa, feita a partir do mangá (q. v.).

Both the English word as well as all well-known romanization systems of the original Japanese アニメ would be *anime*, so it's possible that the word was adopted in Portuguese as-is. But since the word doesn't have any accents, it is prone to be pronounced with a stress on the penultimate syllable [aˈnimɨ].

That said, I also often see *animê*, maybe to parallel *mangá*. For example, the NewPOP Editora writes in their new line of Osamu Tezuka classics

> Osamu Tezuka é o "divisor de águas" da história do mangá e do animê. ...

As I commented above, the original Japanese pronunciation is [aꜜnime], with a drop in pitch after "a", so I think the best approximation would in fact be *ánime*. (The original Japanese for "manga" is 漫画【まんが】 [maŋga], with a flat (low) pitch, so I guess it was convenient to choose *mangá*, because *manga* already means something else.)

My impression is that (Brazilian) Portuguese speakers (mistakenly) think that for Japanese words the stress is often on the last syllable and a stressed final syllable is somewhat of a trademark for Japanese words. In the original Japanese that's not always the case, but many imported Japanese words have a natural *Portuguese* stress on the final syllable, i.e. when they end in I, like *sushi* (could be *súshi*), *caqui* (could be *cáqui*), *hashi* (should be *háshi*).

Comment: `Both the English word as well as all well-known romanization systems of the original Japanese アニメ would be anime` - *but* the japanese `me` sounds like "mé", accented and not otherwise. (Try **[listening](https://translate.google.com/#ja/en/animeeshon)** to the sound by clicking the speaker icon under the text-area for input. Try both "animeeshon" and "anime".) IMO the transliteration is not a solid argument, because it would **never** use accents.

Comment: @ANeves (1) The problem is that one can't produce an [me] sound at the end without also stressing the last syllable. I'm saying, the stress should be on the first syllable `a`, but as you note, this will inevitably cause the `me` to render as [mɨ] and not [me]. (2) I don't know what "argument" you are referring to. I agree that traditional transliteration never uses accents. And my point was that sometimes Japanese words are transliterated (without accents) and pronounced as they are, e.g. _anime_ → [aˈnimɨ].

Comment: @Earthliŋ - *one can't produce an [me] sound at the end without also stressing the last syllable.* This is not true for all variants of Portuguese. In many parts of Rio Grande do Sul it would be perfectly natural to end words with an unstressed [e]. (And, of course, it is often done everywhere for emphasys, for instance in vocatives).

Answer (score 2):

In Brazil, I've encountered many times both ways of pronouncing "Anime": either emphasizing the "ni" (ní) or the "me" (mê). The same occurs with several words with Japanese origin, such as "sushi", "niguiri", "hashi" etc.

Regardless the way it is pronounced, it isn't usual to write Japanese words with accents. We usually adopt the [romaji](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C5%8Dmaji) writing.

Answer (score 0):

In Japanese the words are monotonic, you pronounce it as if you are dividing syllables. and the romanization methods that are common in Brazil usually don´t have accents (Hepburn), because they were created by English speakers. Hence the confusion.

If you want to speak like in Japanese, we Brazilians have to write ANIMÊ. Although the Japanese, when romanizing it, write ANIME.